# Trouble returning proper response to client when using @Async in Spring Boot REST API controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, asynchronous

I am currently working on a Spring Boot REST API that uses the @Async("asyncExecutor") annotation in the controller to make it non-blocking and available to the client after each request. I have intentionally added Thread.sleep for testing purposes only.

The controller is designed to work in the following three cases:

1. If the msisdn is unique, then save the payload to the database.
2. If the msisdn value is already in the database, then send a bad request to the client.
3. If none of the above cases work, then I want to return an internal server error.
   I have included the code below. However, I am having trouble sending a response to the client when a catch block is triggered.

// Controller

```
  @PostMapping("/changeMode")
    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public ResponseEntity<String> SaveSubscriber(@RequestBody Subscribers subscribers) {
        System.out.println("inside changeMode ------------"+subscribers.getMsisdn());
        CompletableFuture<Subscribers> future = userService.SaveSubscriber(subscribers);
        try {
            Subscribers savedUser = future.get(); // wait for the result of the async operation
            System.out.println("sending response changeMode ------------"+subscribers.getMsisdn());
            System.out.println(savedUser != null);
            if (savedUser != null) {
                System.out.println("inside if statement ------------"+subscribers.getMsisdn());
                return ResponseEntity.ok("SUCCESS");
            } else {
                System.out.println("inside else statement ------------"+subscribers.getMsisdn());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Error saving data.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("inside catch statement ------------"+subscribers.getMsisdn());
            System.out.println(e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error saving data.");
        }
```

// service

```
 @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<Subscribers> SaveSubscriber(Subscribers subscribers) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-----------------"+subscribers.getMsisdn()+"------------------"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"-------------inside services");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("inside service method ------------------------------------------"+subscribers.getMsisdn());
        Subscribers savedUser = userRepository.save(subscribers);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(savedUser);
    }
```

It would be helpful to provide some code examples or specific details about your implementation in order to give a clearer understanding of the problem.